# How to map 10 bits to 6 bits in C++ (as efficiently as possible)?

Tags: c++, function, optimization, logic, neural-network

So I know functionally what I would like to happen, I just don't know the best way to make a computer do it... in C++...

I would like to implement a C++ function that maps a 10 bit sequence to a 6 bit sequence.

Nevermind what the bits stand for right now... There are 2^10 = 1024 possible inputs. There are 2^6 = 64 different outputs. Probably lots of patterns. Obviously lots of patterns. But it's complicated. It's s a known mapping, just a complicated mapping.

The output is just one of 64 possibilities.  Maybe they all don't get used.  They probably won't.  But assume they do.

Right now, I'm thinking a quadruple nested switch statement that just takes care of each of the 1024 cases and takes care of business inline, assigning appropriate values to whatever pointer to whatever structure I passed to this function. This seems to be naive and sort of slow. Not that I've implemented it, but that's why I want to ask you first.

This basic function (mapping) will have to be run at every statement node, often more than once, for as many statements this system wishes to support. I ask you, how do I map 10 bits to 6 bits as efficiently as possible in C++?

I know what the mapping is, I know which inputs of 10 bits go with what output of 6 bits... I could totally hard-code that ... somehow? Multi-switch is so ugly. How can I map my 10 bits to 6 bits?! Neural net? Memory muffin? What would you do?

Note to self:  So here is why I am not a fan of the lookup table.  Let's assume all inputs are equally likely (of course they are not, and could be ordered more effectively, but still) then it will take on average 512 memory advances of the array to retrieve the output values... It seems that if you make a (global, why not) binary tree 10 levels deep, you cover the 1024 inputs and can retrieve the output in an average of just 10 steps...  and maybe less if there are good patterns... given a deterministic function that is run so often, how best to retrieve known outputs from known inputs?

Comment: What is wrong with just using &.  Can't you just do `number & 0x3f`, which should just drop the first bits.

Comment: What's the datatype of the input? If it's just an integer, then a lookup-table is perfect. If it isn't, then yes, you will have to go through up to 10 comparisons anyway. In that case, it'll probably be the same speed as massive switch statement. But I can't imagine how long it would take to build a 1024 entry switch statement...

Answer (score 6):

I would use a lookup table of 1024 elements. So hard-code that and just access it by index.

This saves the need for a massive switch statement and will probably be much more readable.

Comment: So a lookup table is just an array that maps an index [0-1023] to a value [0-63]?  I just make that global or what?

Comment: Correct. It would be a global variable. It could be done as global array of type `char` with 1024 elements.

Comment: @Jimmy: Yes, simply an array (char is enough as the element type). I'd suggest making it function-static in the conversion function or file-static in the file where that function is defined.

Comment: I heard that if you use global variables you go to the same place that people that use goto statements go to...

Comment: @Jimmy: That's why function- or file-static. And in any case const!

Comment: @Jimmy: I don't know where you heard that from. Gotos have nothing to do with global variables.

Comment: @Jimmy: Global variables are "evil". The definition of "evil" is roughly "avoid it if you have a non-evil option, but sometimes it's the best tool for the job" (see [C++ FAQ 6.15](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.15)). Sometimes a global object instance is just the right thing and sometimes a goto it just the right thing (though most uses of that has to do with C not having exceptions).

Comment: @Jimmy Global variables have their uses---there not like `goto`.  But this is not one of them (and Mysticial didn't say anything about global variables): a local static (`const`, to be sure of avoiding any threading issues) is the way to go.

Comment: @James Yeah, I was just playing puritan...  just want minimal load time with minimal run time, and willing to sacrafice a second of load time for an eon of runtime...

Comment: @James Kanze: For a table this large, I would make it a `const` global and put it in it's own header file. I can't imagine trying to scroll through that if it was embedded into the function itself. (Ok, maybe 1024 of `char`s isn't that bad, but I've dealt with larger tables of 64-bit integers where each had to be on it's own line.)

Comment: @Mysticial The scrolling can be an issue.  I usually live with it (and since my editor supports folding, I can avoid it there), but in no case would I make it global (in the sense of being accessible from another translation unit).  If nothing else, I'd forward declare it in an anonymous namespace, the define it at the end of the file (thus avoiding the scrolling issue).

Comment: @James Kanze: That works too. I guess it's up to preference. The tables that I deal with are typically script generated and can be easily 10,000 lines long. So I put them in a header, but it's not a "global" header. It only gets included into the file that uses.

Comment: @Jimmy: global *variables* are best avoided, however here we are talking about a global *constant*, and those are a corner stone of good programming. You just have to be careful about where and how you define them, because of C++ non-handling of initialization/destruction order :/

Comment: @Mysticial For generated code (regardless of the size, or how it is generated), I totally agree.  Generated code must imperatively be kept separate from hand written code---you don't want generated code under source code control, for example.  I'll admit, however, that I didn't think in those terms when you said "header"---I don't think of them as headers, even if they formally are.  (For one thing, they often aren't included at the "head" of the source, but much later.)

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your definition of efficiency.

1. Time-efficient: Look-up table.
2. Space-efficient: Use a Karnaugh map.

Comment: A Karnaugh map will still have 1024 entries.  Plus more complicated code to access it.  So it will be less space efficient than a simple array: `static char const table[1024] = { ... };`

Comment: The Karnaugh map is a tool to get a simplified boolean expression. So, ideally, you'd get something like 10 additive terms that construct the whole expression and replace the 1024 table entry. Or, in the worst case, you'd realize that your whole table is necessary because it is irreducible.

Comment: @thiton OK.  I thought you meant implementing a Karnaugh map in your code.

Comment: I think you two have a *great* (like in great work, not greatly useful) idea on your hand: Boost.Karnaugh! You write the complicated boolean expression, boost simplifies it at compile-time by training a neural net implemented fully in template meta-programming, unleashing it on the expression's truth table and gaining a simplified expression at the mere cost of a few hour's compiling time and a few thousand hours of time spent programming this garbage. :-)

Comment: (Naturally, Boost.Quine-McCluskey might be a bit more useful, but not half as convoluted. Just stating it here for completeness.)

Comment: Agreed, there aren't nearly enough Boost libraries that require you to manually increase your compiler's template recursion depth in order to use them for even the simplest task. This fills an important niche.

Answer (score 2):

Use a look-up table of size 1024.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map to *some particular* 6-bit values, use a lookup table of **size 64** (not 1024!) after dividing by 16. This will fit into the cache more easily than a 16-times redundant 1024-entry table (and, the 2 extra cycles for a right shift outweight the cost of a possible cache miss by far).

Otherwise, if a simple sequential mapping is fine, just do a divide by 16.

1024/64 = 16, so dividing by 16 (a right shift with compiler optimizations turned on), maps to 6 bits (sequentially). It cannot get more efficient than that.